# How to parse JSON from MyMemory translation with PHP?

Tags: php, json, translation

As Google Translate API is not free anymore, I try to get the translations from http://mymemory.translated.net/doc/spec.php

My PHP page for example

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-type: application/json');
$_POST['value']=="Hello everybody";
// URI to get italian from english
$translate_it=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?q=".$_POST['value']."&langpair=en|it"));
```

I'm not an object developper, and I don't konw how to acces the data...

How can I get only the field "translation" from this ?
http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?q=Hello%20everybody&langpair=en|it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are using `echo`.

to see the content, try using :

```
var_dump($translate_it);
```

One way to use your new json variable would like this

```
$translate_it->responseData;
```

Here is one translation:

```
echo $translate_it->matches[0]->translation;
```

**UPDATE:**

You can loop through the matches using for each:

```
foreach ($translate_it->matches[0] as $obj){
   echo $obj->translation;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to get the translation ? How to build the way to ? $translate_it->responseData['translation']; ?

Comment: @Valky see my last line. You will have to go through the matches array to see the data you need. use the `var_dump($translate_it)` as a reference

Comment: Perfect, I see... How to do a foreach() to see all matches[] translations ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've checked your answer

Answer (score 0):

[json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) will, but default return an object - `stdClass`. The second (optional) parameter will have it return an array. Either way, it's not just a simple string when it's been decoded.

`print_r($translate_it)`, or `var_dump($translate_it)` will show the structure of the object, or array.